# Can setup.py / pip require a certain version of another package IF that package is already installed?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, python-packaging

I have two python packages ([locust-swarm](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-swarm/) and [locust-plugins](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/)). Neither has a strict requirement to the other, but they can work together, and my users install them separately.

Sometimes there is a breaking change in one or the other, and I want to make sure nobody installs incompatible versions (by updating package A but not package B, for example). Is there a way to specify a minimum version of this "pseudo-dependency" and fail the install if it is not satisfied? A check that is *only done if the other package is already installed*.

I do *not* want to add one package as a dependency of the other and force users of package A to install package B, just to be able to handle this case.

Probably this question has been asked before, but I couldnt find an answer.

Comment: I can not think of a solution for this, since there is no "dependency relation" between the 2 things... -- You could maybe hack something together with "extra / optional" dependencies that would get you close-ish, but I do not think it would actually work well enough.

Comment: You probably need to do the version compatibility check at run-time. Something like `if importlib.metadata.version('locust-plugins') < '1.2.3': raise IncompatiblePlugins()` (pseudo-code).

Comment: I think you may be right sinoroc. Or maybe it can be done in a post install hook? (that is more of a nice to have though)

Comment: There are no "post-install hooks" in Python packaging ecosystem. -- You could try asking your question [here](https://discuss.python.org/c/packaging/14) -- I wonder if what you want to do exists in other packaging ecosystems (Node, Rust, Java, etc.), looks like it might be "peer dependency in `npm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this in your `A/setup.py` file (and the same in your `B/setup.py` file, just change `package_B_name` to `package_A_name`:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.find_spec(f'{package_B_name}')
if spec is not None:
    requirements_list.append(f'{package_B_name}>={package_B_version}')
```

Note that this only works in Python3.3+ and only source distributions. It will not work when installing from a binary wheel (.whl)

Comment: Sounds promising, and worked great when I did a local install (pip install .), but I added this to locust-swarm (https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-swarm/commit/cf19ed0237deba34d1f68efe40a35b509d86794b) and published it as 4.1.0, and it does not require anything :-/ Maybe the requirements are "burned" into the published package?

Comment: You can add prints and see if the package has been added to the list... anyway if it worked locally, then it looks like maybe something in the new version isn't right?

Comment: Huh. I wonder what I changed - now it works :) Perhaps I had already installed locust-swarm from local, and then installing from pypi didnt actually do anything, because it felt my current install was newer. Thanks! (i made a small edit to your answer - without it I ended up having a requirement that was actually a list of characters :)

Comment: No wait, now it stopped working again :(

Comment: Ah. I think i get it now. For this to work it has to be a source distribution (not a binary wheel). I must have gotten lucky once and installed *just* as my build was finishing and there was only a source version uploaded. I’ll check this hypothesis (by disabling binary packages) later tonight.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to convert a requirements.txt to a setup.py file in accordance, try this for example:

```
my-package>=minimum.version
```

This checks for if the package is greater than this specific version or is this minimum version, therefore making a minimum version.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly but you can specify the minimum required version in the `install_requires` array in the setup function like so.

```
install_requires=['locust-swarm >= 1.2', 'locust-plugins >= 1.1']
```

I hope this answers your question, if it doesn't, let me know, and I will look into it further.

Comment: The question states that one can not be a dependency of the other. So it seems to me like this does not answer the question.

Comment: Yeah but I don't think theres a clean alternative